# Thread Vs ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am newbie in .NET. I am using Threads in my project. please check my code below -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        private void Amadeus(object str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program objClass = new Program();

            //One way to call Amadeus Method...
            Thread objThread = new Thread(objClass.Amadeus);
            objThread.Start("Amadeus without ParameterizedThreadStart");

            //Other way to call Amadeus Method...
            ParameterizedThreadStart objParamThread = new ParameterizedThreadStart(objClass.Amadeus);
            Thread ObjThreadParam = new Thread(objParamThread);
            ObjThreadParam.Start("Amadeus with ParameterizedThreadStart");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Can you please tell me what is the difference between above both way as both are doing same work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same. Read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx#Y100).

> Visual Basic and C# users can omit the ThreadStart or
>   ParameterizedThreadStart delegate constructor when creating a thread.
>   In Visual Basic, use the AddressOf operator when passing your method
>   to the Thread constructor; for example, Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf
>   ThreadProc). In C#, simply specify the name of the thread procedure.
>   The compiler selects the correct delegate constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are doing the same thing.

You can create a thread by passing in a function with a ThreadStart (void ThreadStart()) or ParameterisedThreadStart  (void ParameterisedThreadStart(Object x)) signature.

The compiler is working out which constructor to call from the type of parameter you are passing into the constructor.